# How did everyone end up on Kamine island?

Tags: code-geass

When Lelouch ordered Suzaku to live, Schneitzels Avalon started blasting everything.

But how did everyone get to Kamine island?
How did the other Black Knights get out of that mess and not go to Kamine island?
How come Black Knights couldn't know where the other team has ended up, they were just next to each other?
How did Princess Euphemia end up there?

And there is a scene were C.C is possibly talking to Marianne and there is a mention that she sent them there? Whats going on, seems like I missed something?

Answer (score 4):

We see later on when Suzaku is remembering what he did when Lelouch ordered him to live what happened, Suzaku closed the cockpit of the Lancelot with Lelouch with him and went to escape, while i can't remember it entirely, he probably picked up Euphie on the way while Kallen chased after him knowing Zero was inside.

Because the Hadron Cannon was unfocused, C.C must have used the confusion to do something to the ruins remotely, possibly using the Thought Elevator, to send them to the island, it might have been area of effect as she probably was only targeting Lelouch but Suzaku, Euphie and Kallen was within the vicinity. C.C probably had planned that Lelouch would learn more of Geass, of Charles and V.V and of the Thought Elevator so that Lelouch would be prepared to grant her wish in the end.

How the Black Knight got out of the Avalon's attack, well as i said the Hadron Cannon was unfocused, it was still a prototype and Lloyd expresses how annoyed he is later on when Rakshata is able to perfect it by focusing the beams, because of the way the Hadron Cannon attacked and what we see it's assumed that the Black Knights retreated.

As for how they couldn't get in contact with Lelouch or Kallen, i'm quite sure what ever C.C did separated Suzaku and Kallen from their Knightmares and obviously they at the time were relying on their comms within the Knightmares so didn't carry radios, this is proven by the fact that the playback of Suzaku disobeying order was recorded in the Lancelot, the Britannian forces probably weren't aware of Suzaku or Euphie being on the island as they where there by chance on a separate mission investigating the ruins which Bartley suspects was the reason why Japan (and a number of other nations) was invaded in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If you watch the end of the previous episode, and when Lelouch and Suzaku meet up, you'll note that there is a mysterious boy observing events, shown very briefly. It is this boy, who you are not yet introduced to, who is responsible.

Given what we know of him from later events, he probably sends them there to have the events screw Lelouch and/or Euphemia's plans up without being too obvious, but probably benefited from Lelouch's interaction with the Thought Elevator as well.

Comment: I'm not sure that could be V.V's motives if he was the cause. Euphie at the time wasn't planning on creating the Specially Administrated Zone and it wasn't till afterwords when she reunited with Nunnally did she decide to plan it (her reasons explained on the G1 before Lelouch's Geass activated) and all the SPZ would have done is possibly cause the Order to loose 1 Geass Ruins site which, if Bartly is correct, Britannia could just wage war again to take it back (he suggests the reason Japan was conquered was for the ruins and not for it's Sakuradite)

Answer (score 0):

I think the implication was that V.V. needed a Geass user to open the Thought Elevator and Lelouch was the closest one. Or he did for laughs, as C.C. assumed in Episode 19.

Although less likely, I personally like that other theory that the "impervious observer" C.C. was talking with is the [Caretaker of Spacetime](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Caretaker_of_Spacetime) that appears in *Code Geass: Akito the Exiled* OVAs.